# CSS position:sticky undone by <div container> (and others)

Tags: ios, css, css-position

I'll start by saying I'm a complete beginner at this. I'm setting up a personal website about my research which will one day expand into a group website when I have my own research group, anyway.

I have a menu which I want to stick to the top of the page when scrolled past, and this works fine. However as soon as the bottom of the menu reaches a < div...> of any sort, it decides to no longer stick - **but this is only a problem in Safari** for iOS as far as I've tested it (only have access to Macs and iPhones in my household).

Please see: www.capgoodwin.com/index.html for this in action. I have set that page up to have a whole bunch of breaks < br >, then a < div class="container">< /div > which is empty, followed by more breaks. As soon as you hit the  on iOS Safari, the nav bar disappears.

I guess the relevant files are www.capgoodwin.com/index.html and www.capgoodwin.com/style.css , I'd love to paste specific bits of the code but I don't know which bits are actually wrong, so I've put the whole thing in.

I hope someone can help, cheers.

```js
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("nav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family:sans-serif;
} 



//--------------- font stuff -----{}
h1 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
}
h6 {
    color: white;
    font-style: italic;

    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    
}

p7 {
    width:10px;
}

p8 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

p9 {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

p10 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 1em;
}

p11 {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 1em;
}

p12 {
    color: orange;
    font-size: 1em;
}

p13 {
    color: green;
    font-size: 1em;
}

p14 {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 1em;
}
//--------------- font stuff -----{}

.jumbotron {
    padding: 0.5%;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 661px) {
    .jumbotron .img {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        opacity: 0.2;
        background: #000000 url("img/topbar2.jpg") center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-position: 0em -48em
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
    .jumbotron .img {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        opacity: 0.2;
        background: #000000 url("img/topbar2.jpg") center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        background-position: 0em -15em
    }
}


hr.style1 {
    border-color: white;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 0.1px;
}

hr.style2  {
    border-color: darkgrey;
    width: 75%;
}

//--------------- menu stuff -----{}
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    background-color: #484747;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    

}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
    background-color: #b7b7b7;

}

.topnav a:hover {
    color: black;
    text-decoration-line: none;
}

.topnav a:hover:not(.active) {
    color: rgba(79, 160, 255, 0.9);
    text-decoration-line: none;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
  .topnav a:not(.active) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: sticky;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1%;
    top: 0.19em;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

//--------------- menu stuff -----{}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>CAP Goodwin</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/navlogo.JPG">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>    
<!top banner start---------------------->      
<div style="background-color: #484747" class="jumbotron text-center">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <h1>Conrad Goodwin</h1>
    <small><h6>Inorganic and Organometallic Chemistry</h6></small>
</div>
<!top banner end---------------------->  

<!menu bar start---------------------->      
<div class="topnav" id="nav">
  <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="research.html">Research Focus</a>
  <a href="pubs.html">Publications</a>
  <a href="crystallography.html">The Functional Crystallographer</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div> 
<!menu bar end---------------------->     





    
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

   <div class="container"></div> 
        
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    
    


            
<!contact details---------------------->     
<div class="center-block">    
        <div class="text-center">
<hr class="style2">
            
            <p9>
            School of Chemistry, The University of Manchester,<br>
            Oxford Road, Manchester, M13 9PL, U.K.<br>
            <p10>Office</p10>: 5.63 | <p11>Lab</p11>: 5.52<br>
            <p12>e</p12>: conrad.goodwin@manchester.ac.uk<br>
            <p13>t</p13>: +44(0)7545885848<br>
            </p9>    
            <a href="https://twitter.com/ConradGoodwin?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @ConradGoodwin</a>
            <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </div>
</div>
    
</body>      
</html>
    
<!dependencies---------------------->      
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
<script src="bootstrap/js/nav.js"></script>          
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: You need to put any markup that you want to be seen inside the body tag you have all of your menu and header outside of the body.  The body tag should hold basically everything that is not located in the head tag so basically everything that you actually see on a webpage should be placed in the body tag.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that, figured out how to add it in. I've trimmed all of the fat from the HTML file and pasted the whole thing in, but I have no idea which bits of the CSS are causing the problem (if any) so it's all there. I hope it's not too long. Actually, usefully, the code-snippet runner has the same problem. The sticky menu goes off screen when it hits the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use webkit for this like this:

```
<style>
div.sticky {
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
top: 0;
}
.example {
width: 100%;
height: 900px;
background-color: #ddd;
display: inline-block;
}

.headerExample {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background: linear-gradient(black, grey);
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
</style>
<div class="sticky">
<div class="headerExample">
<p> Some Text...</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="example">
<h1> Some more text </h1>
<p> Some more text </p>
</div>
```

And voila, the top sticks and stays!

**google webkit for begginers for more info**

Comment: there is no JavaScript required to make a sticky header. :D